# QUERY ERROR, can't update query in DB

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, rest, slim

Today I tried to create an update function to my REST web service with SLIM framework.
But I got this problem.
I had stuck with my queries, because it didn't work well.

this is my class include query

```
       public function updateUserCard($card_id, $user_id, $barcode) 
       {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE user_cards uc, cards c
                                          SET uc.barcode = ?                                  
                                          WHERE uc.id = ? 
                                            AND uc.id = c.card_id 
                                            AND uc.user_id = ?");
            if($stmt == FALSE)
            {
                die($this->conn->error);
            }
            else 
            {
                $stmt->bind_param("iis", $user_id, $card_id, $barcode);
                $stmt->execute();
                $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
                $stmt->close();
                return $num_affected_rows > 0;
            }
      }
```

I tried to update the 'barcode' column with new value. But it didn't work.

And this is my code in index.php

```
        $app->put('/cards/users/:id', 'authenticate', function($id) use ($app) 
        {
            // check for required params
            verifyRequiredParams(array('barcode'));

            global $user_id;
            $barcode = $app->request->put('barcode');


            $db = new UserCard();
            $response = array();

            // updating card
            $result = $db->updateUserCard($user_id, $card_id, $barcode);
            if ($result) 
            {
                // card updated successfully
                $response["error"] = false;
                $response["message"] = "Card updated successfully";
            } 
            else 
            {
                // card failed to update
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "Card failed to update. Please try again!";
            }
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

The responses always be like `$response["message"] = "Card failed to update. Please try again!";`

Did I wrote a wrong code ?
Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: Your function updateUserCard takes two parameters with ($user_id, $barcode) and at the time of calling updateUserCard you are passing barcode first and then userid. Check this line, $result = $db->updateUserCard($barcode, $user_id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have incorrect order while passing parameters for calling updateUserCard.

Your function updateUserCard takes two parameters with ($user_id, $barcode) and at the time of calling updateUserCard you are passing barcode first and then userid.

Check this line, `$result = $db->updateUserCard($barcode, $user_id);`

Comment: Have you corrected the order of argument and tried?

Comment: Yes,  haha I still don't  understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

There is no $card_id inside function updateUserCard($user_id, $barcode)

You either forget to pass it in parameters, made it global, fetched it from '$this-> ' or got it from elsewhere.

Comment: I already tried, but it still didn't work. I think my queries goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your index.php code. Try the below code:

```
 $app->put('/cards/users/:id', 'authenticate', function($id) use ($app) 
        {
            // check for required params
            verifyRequiredParams(array('barcode'));

            global $user_id;
            $barcode = $app->request->put('barcode');


            $db = new UserCard();
            $response = array();

            // updating card
            $result = $db->updateUserCard($card_id, $user_id, $barcode);
            if ($result) 
            {
                // card updated successfully
                $response["error"] = false;
                $response["message"] = "Card updated successfully";
            } 
            else 
            {
                // card failed to update
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "Card failed to update. Please try again!";
            }
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

Comment: still didn't work, always  $response["message"] = "Card failed to update. Please try again!";